# Not able to run HTTPS content with Charles proxy on android emulator , even after installing certificate

Tags: android, android-emulator, charles-proxy

I have to monitor react native HTTPS calls from an APP so I am using charles proxy.
I have made all necessary changes : in proxy settings, have put '*' in SSL settings.
I have changed my emulator's proxy to that of charles local IP.
But till now i am only able to monitor HTTP sites.
I have downloaded certificate but its making no effect on the result and i am still getting that "Your connection is not private .....insecure" error. 
i have downloaded certificate from here http://www.charlesproxy.com/getssl/
.
Can some help me , i am totally stuck over here.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is 2 years ago, but in case someone comes to here with the same question, I got the emulator to process also the https requests through Charles Proxy.

Instead of relying on this [useless stupid proxy setting panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1EL4.png) provided by Android Studio, you should:

1. Head to **Settings > Network & Internet > Wi-Fi**.
2. Click the cogwheel icon of "AndroidWifi".
3. Click the pencil icon at the top to edit
4. Change the Proxy from None to Manual, then input the local IP address and the correct port into the fields below.

Now your https requests will be routed to Charles Proxy!